# use of "throws IOException" in java file handling

Tags: java, exception, file-io

why we use 'Throws IOException' in java File handling. i mean what is the purpose of using these two words in File handling??
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *throws* word means that the code could enter an error state, the *IOExeption* word describes the error state.

This means that you will have to put any method that *throws IOExcepion* into a *try ... catch* block where you can write code to make your program respond to the error state appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably referring to [checked exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). They are used to indicate that a method  could potentially throw one of the listed exceptions so that the callers need to explicitly catch them or be marked with the same exceptions list.